# Javascript markers handling events

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, addeventlistener

Hi i have created some code where the user selects the location the number and the color of a marker and then the marker that he has selected is added on the map. Is there any possible way of adding an event listener lets say mouse over so when you get the mouse over the marker that he added it changes lets say color or type. Here is my code:

```
function dropmarker()
   {
var lat = prompt ('Latitude'); var lng = prompt('Longitude');
var mark = document.getElementById('mark').value;
var style = document.getElementById('number').value;

switch(mark + ' ' + style)
{
  case 'blue one':
      new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map:map,
            icon:'blue1.png'
        });
    break;
case 'blue two':
      new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map:map,
            icon:'blue2.png'
        });

mark1 = new google.maps.MarkerImage('custom1.png',
new google.maps.Size(32,37),
new google.maps.Point(0,0),
new google.maps.Point(16,35));


}
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() 
{
 marker.setIcon(mark1);
});

}

 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
```

How can i add some code so when i put the mouse over the marker it changes color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to create the marker, and then place the listener on the created marker.
e.g.

```
var theMarker;
var icon2 = "imageB.png";
var originalIcon;
switch(mark + ' ' + style)
{
     case 'blue one':
           theMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                      map:map,
                     icon:'blue1.png'
                    });
           originalIcon = 'blue1.png';
    break;
    case 'blue two':
          theMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                     map:map,
                     icon:'blue2.png'
                     });
          originalIcon = 'blue2.png';
}

google.maps.event.addListener(theMarker, 'mouseover', function() 
{
    theMarker.setIcon(icon2);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(theMarker, 'mouseout', function() 
{
    theMarker.setIcon(originalIcon ); 
});
```

Comment: it seems that neither this is working. I get the logic it seems fine but code wise the marker still doesnt change mouse over. damn

Comment: I made a quick edit. I changed the line inside the listener callback. Any chance you can get a JSFiddle of your code?

Comment: hey can you check one of my recent questions please and see if you can help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CSS? Something along these lines:

```
#mark:hover { color: red}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your answer, I havent tried it but i need some js code in order to implement what i need. Thank you though. :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, then maybe something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() 
{
     marker.setIcon(icon2);
});
```

Comment: can you check my question please i modified my code ? I edit it but its not working. it drops the marker but it does nothing on mouse over.